# It is possible to change the Data Center without restarting the game?

Tags: apex-legends

When I started Apex Legends, I selected the "Sao Paulo - Google Compute Engine (GCE) 2" Data Center but I no longer want to play on it.

It is possible to change the current Data Center without restarting the game?

Answer (score 1):

while in main menu on pc you could also change to offline mode in origin and right back to online (tab out of the game for that), back in the game you should get the title screen and be able to click on the accessibility settings aswell

Answer (score 0):

When you load the game do not press "continue" and wait there for 90 seconds approximately, then a pop windows will appear.

Comment: I'm already on the main menu, so...

Comment: Which platform you are trying PC, XB,PS?

Comment: PlayStation 4 and PC

Comment: Console, 1. wait 2 minutes on title screen , 2. enter accessibility settings and exit 3. Press r3.... Pc. 1. Wait 60 seconds, 2. Click on accessibility settings and exit, 3. Data center menu will apper at the bottom